# Is a firewall required for a SOHO network?

Tags: firewalls

Would a firewall router be required on a SOHO network ?

The network has a LAN to LAN VPN (no end user in).

There is no server / services on the network other than some consumer IOT devices, the network is mainly used for end user browsing, voip etc.

For a network like that if there was a firewall what would it typically be monitoring / blocking / allowing and would a firewall in fact be required or overkill ?

Comment: Your question is very opinion based, however I have closed as a dupe of that one rather than just close.

Answer (score 0):

There's very little that's *required*.  However, is it a good idea?  That's possibly a better question.

Given that the O in SOHO stands for "Office", it would be a good idea to firewall that traffic off.  IoT devices, as a rule, aren't built with security in mind and some of them can be/are used in botnets.  If nothing else, blocking incoming traffic would be a useful principle to place on that network to keep those devices from being attacked.